# Bootstrap 4 ordering classes not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to reorder my columns when the screen size is small(sm) using Bootstrap 4. But instead, they are being reordered on a large screen size and remain in original position on small screens.

Current code:

```
    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row project-container" id="project1">
                       <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 order-sm-12">
                            <div class="project-description">
                                <h2>Meteor Shower</h2>
                                <span>Video Game,Unity Game Engine</span>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum 
                                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, numquam. dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, quidem.voluptates aut atque obcaecati unde. Repellendus eligendi soluta tempore similique sunt?</p>
                                <div class="visit-website">Visit Website</div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-5 video-container order-sm-1" >
                           <div class="videoWrapper">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DzFfqFzir2o" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it should be order-12 and order-1, not order-sm-12 and order-sm-1

Comment: @Sheldon Scott I want them to order when the screen size is small not instantly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But instead they are being reorder at large size but being in original wanted position in small size.

Bootstrap 4 is "mobile-first".

So, a class like `order-sm-12` means: From the small (sm) screen size and up i.e. larger. Not the other way around.

To solve the issue, you add the `order-sm-first order-md-2` classes to the video column. So, you only need the order classes for one column in this case. (remove the order class from the first column)

Here's a complete, working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row project-container" id="project1">
        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
            <div class="project-description">
                <h2>Meteor Shower</h2>
                <span>Video Game,Unity Game Engine</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum 
                    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, numquam. dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, quidem.voluptates aut atque obcaecati unde. Repellendus eligendi soluta tempore similique sunt?</p>
                <div class="visit-website">Visit Website</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 video-container order-first order-md-2" >
            <div class="videoWrapper">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DzFfqFzir2o" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand the problem. But what is the solution. col-md-12

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Lets suppose there are two columns A and B. On md size it must be first A and then B. But in sm size it must be B first and then A

Comment: Must the video come first on smaller screens or second?

Comment: Video must come first on small but on second on large

Comment: Check the updated code snippet. (I didn't fix the other issues you have there).

Comment: video is still on second on sm size

Comment: Video switches to first on small.

Comment: it doesnot it is still on second. In fact no change at all

Comment: Please, just click the "run code snippet" button above, expand to full page and then resize the window...

Comment: What do you see when the page switches to one-column layout? Does the video come first or second there?

Comment: In code snippet it is working . But in my local it is not working

Comment: Right. That's why you need to copy my entire code snippet.

Comment: Does it has to do with bootstrap version. I copied the whole but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164466/discussion-between-unity-hour-and-webdevbooster).

Comment: Not if you have Bootstrap 4.0.0. Remember, I had removed `order-sm-12` from the first column. You might have missed that.

Comment: Since my code snippet is working (as you confirmed) and since I haven't heard anything back from you in the chat, I assume this question has been answered. Please click the checkmark next to my question to accept it. And in case you have other issues with your local code, please post a new question and include your local code there.

Comment: "Bootstrap 4 is 'mobile-first'." - This is key! Thanks for this useful reminder.