# Bootstrap 4 ordering class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a question about the bootstrap 4.1 reordering. According to the documentation:

> **Reordering**
>
> Use .order- classes for controlling the visual order of
>   your content. These classes are responsive, so you can set the order
>   by breakpoint (e.g., `.order-1` `.order-md-2`). Includes support for 1
>   through 12 across all five grid tiers.

I've tried to set the reordering only on small and medium screens, using the `.order`classes as showed in the docs, but it will reorder the contents also on larger breakpoints, I'm doing this wrong?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 order-sm-2">
        <!-- some contents here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 order-sm-1">
        <!-- some contents here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need re-order in larger breakpoints, because bootstrap is mobile first approach, (it means it is using `min-width` in media queries), so when only using `sm` it will apply properties from `sm` and up (including `md` and `lg`).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 order-sm-2 order-lg-1">
      mobile 2nd and then desktop 1st
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 order-sm-1 order-lg-2">
      mobile 1st and then desktop 2st
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One more thing to know about `order` in BS4, is that you can you use `order-X-first`, `order-X-last` and `order-X-0`, so here a snippet with those classes. You can see them in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38248132/3448527)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 order-sm-last order-lg-first">
      mobile 2nd and then desktop 1st
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 order-sm-first order-lg-last">
      mobile 1st and then desktop 2st
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So to clarify, it will display the order as 2 and then 1 only on smaller screens, right? And from small screens and above it displays 1 and then 2?

Comment: just toggle `full page` in the snippet to see result but yes

Comment: This is the solution I've adopted, I was not considering the mobile first approach of the boostrap framework, so I have misunderstood how to correctly use the `.order` class utility

Comment: I was trying the different solutions posted, Your answer is the most correct here after the update, The problem I has was about the wrong `.order` class use. I've tried to fix it using `.order-1 order-lg-2` and this worked, but I'm not too experienced with columns reordering in booststrap so I assume as you said in a comment that mine is the wrong way.

Comment: you need to understand flexbox order, which bootstrap order is based

Comment: Your wording confused me, but your examples are very clear, +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of Bootstrap and is expected.

To say it in short words, all bootstrap's breakpoint suffixes (`-sm` `-md` ...) work  from that breakpoint upward.

So if you set `col-sm-6` that means your column will be half the size of row from in `sm` breakpoint and `md` and `lg` unless you overwrite it (e.g. `col-md-2` ).

It all goes back [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) (using min-width in media queries)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how you can do this with media queries:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
       <!-- some content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9">
       <!-- some content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 move-down">
       <!-- some content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 move-up">
       <!-- some content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <!-- some content -->
   </div>
</div>

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .move-down {
        order: 2;
    }
    .move-up {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing order-1, this sets the default for larger screens

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 order-1 order-sm-2">
    <!-- some contents here -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 order-2 order-sm-1">
    <!-- some contents here -->
</div>
```

Source: [Column ordering in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but it will order the columns in the wrong way. I've found a lot of peoples with the same problem but this question was solving my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598915/bootstrap-4-ordering-classes-not-working

Comment: Ahh I see. So it would have ignored the `order-2` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected your answer, this is the working solution who I've adopted. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @user9741470 You can't/shoun't edit an answer just to make it correct and give it the accepted answer.
And other thing you had in your snippet `order-sm` not `order`, so how come you edited this answer to this and then accepted?.

Btw the `Have you tried doing order-1, this sets the default for larger screens` is wrong.  because `order` is for extra-small screens and up.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Just trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into some issues with this as well. Here's the following code that got it to work for me:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-2 order-1">
                <!-- some contents here -->Content1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-1 order-2">
                <!-- some contents here -->Content2
             </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: Removed .order-md class from respective columns.

Comment: you don't need the `order-md` here and doesn't answer OP's question, given OP wants to start at `sm` and change at `lg`

Comment: Yes I'm aware. Was trying to brute force a solution but forgot to clean up. Thanks.