# Ordering Bootstrap 5 columns when resizing the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to reverse the staking order in bootstrap

I have the following 2 columns next to each other in 1 row

Col A - Col B (on every screen except mobiles)

When the screen is made smaller or is loaded on a mobile device I want the columns to stack then in reverse order

Col B

Col A (on a mobile and when resized on every other screen)

HTML

```
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <p>A</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>B</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.order-` [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes) classes for controlling the visual order of your content. mix it with breakpoints to make the order like `.order-sm-*` or `.order-md-*`

for eg

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 order-sm-2">
```

So the code would be like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 order-sm-2">
      <p>A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 order-sm-1">
      <p>B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the use case for 'order'.  All the above code does is put B in front of A regardless of screen size.  A bit like swapping <p>A</><p>B</> over like so <p>B</><p>A</> or simply cut-copy-and-paste the B col code and put it in front of A col...it's pointless?

Comment: What I wat to do is re-order the automatic stacking of these cols when the screen size is adjusted to a smaller size.  It's not rocket science and I'm surprised such a trivial ask is not coved by bootstrap or if there is I can't find it....

Comment: The above code does work on the screen breakpoints, bootstrap has got it covered with order class. May be you are using it incorrectly. Create a working codepen and we can check

Comment: I don't have a codepen account.  Can you show it working?

Comment: You're right, I've managed to get it working by adding order-first as per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598915/bootstrap-4-ordering-classes-not-working thanks for the pointer